# Getting 204 respose code by POSTwith json entity in it

Tags: java, jackson, jersey-2.0

Not sure how to make this code getting 200 response back. It seems there is "no content"/204 in the request/response.

```
private Response doPostRequestAsJSON(String url) {

    ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
    clientConfig.register(JacksonFeature.class);
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(clientConfig);

    AuthLoginElement authLoginElement = new AuthLoginElement("user1", "pass1");

    WebTarget webTarget = client.target(url);

    Response response = webTarget.request("application/json")
            .post(Entity.entity(authLoginElement, "application/json"));

    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`204 No Content` is a valid choice for the response, see [RFC 7231 Section-6.3.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.5):

> The 204 (No Content) status code indicates that the server has successfully fulfilled the request and that there is no additional content to send in the response payload body.  Metadata in the response header fields refer to the target resource and its selected representation after the requested action was applied [...].

Usually the accessing client (you) wants or needs to have some kind of response, for example to receive the remote ID of the posted content, to be able to access the resource afterwards (like with `GET ./foo/{ID}/bar`). Therefore metadata in the response header fields should be included ... *have a look after that in your response*.

Afaig you can't manipulate your request to get a [200 OK](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.1) - except, the server provides some 'special' features.

Have a nice day ...

Comment: yeah. I guess I'm Ok and can live with that as soon as it works/sends message properly:)